# How to determine if a CD is in CD-ROM drive

Tags: c++, windows

I was wondering if there is a Windows API that can tell me if there is a empty CD is inside a CD-ROM/DVD-Rom drive.

I've already looked at GetVolumeInformation(), but that only brings back information on the actual CD-ROM drive, not the media that is inside it, if there's even a CD in it or not.

All I'm trying to do is see if there's a cd in the drive or not and return a boolean value.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Removed qt tag, nothing to do with qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `GetFileAttributes()` on the root directory. `GetFileAttributes()` is quite optimized as it's commonly used as a check whether a file or directory exists.

Another method is to call `GetDiskFreeSpace`, which (despite its name) also returns the total disk size.

The Shell also has some useful functions. `SHGetDriveMedia` will tell you what's loaded, but you should first call `GetDriveType()`.

Comment: Ok, I tried them all, but none of those commands work.  They just simply do not read the media.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Drake0727: that's quite weird. Are you saying that `GetDiskFreeSpace()` doesn't actually return the CD size ?

Comment: No it does not.  Getfileattributes does not return anything; Getdiskfreespace I am already using in a different function, and it works for HD and flash drives, but not CD-ROM; and SHGetDriveMedia is a windows vista and up API, I need XP compatibility unfortunately.

Comment: @MSalters there is no filesystem on a blank CD, so there is no way to tell how much free space there is.

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is most probably IMAPI.

I think this article here could be of help for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163992.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use DeviceIoControl API passing IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY as the dwIoControlCode. This will check if a particular disc drive is ready i. e. has a disc in it and, of course, the tray is closed. Check the [DeviceIoControl](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=Z32oUYDEMe6UiQfk2oCwCA&usg=AFQjCNFqWhit9BITgmlQwBoLHMwAwUH1kw&sig2=7TzzxwwaSvH_zvLy0WByYg&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aGc) MSDN documentation for more info on this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
// FROM VISTA to ....
BOOL CDYesNo(WCHAR letter) {// like F

 DWORD pdwMediaContent=0;  
 BOOL ret =1; 

 WCHAR catw[3];  // create wchar string
 catw[0]=letter; 
 catw[1]=L':';
 catw[2]=NULL;  `enter code here`
     
 HRESULT rcd=SHGetDriveMedia( catw, &pdwMediaContent); 
 //rcd normally is S_OK, maybe tested.

 if(pdwMediaContent ==0) ret=0;   

return ret;  // 0=empty
}
```

Comment: This question was answered previously, and OP stated he requires XP compat.